# Polymorphism with type variable?

Tags: haskell

The title might not be appropriate, so please read on.

What I initially want is the following : I'm writing a 2D Vector data

```
data Vect a = Vect a a deriving (Show)
```

and want to write a `norm :: Vect a -> Double` function that works for all `Vect a` where a is an instance of `Integral` or `Floating`.

For Double, I can wrote:

```
norm :: Vect Double -> Double
norm (Vect x y) = sqrt  $ x^2 + y^2
```

But I want this function to also work with `Vect Int`. I can write another function like:

```
normFromInt :: (Integral a) => Vect a -> Double
normFromInt (Vect x y) = sqrt . fromIntegral $ x^2 + y^2
```

Having two functions seems rather awkward. What are the good ways of achieving this?

---

I tried to use special class for this:

```
class Vectorlike a where
    norm :: a -> Double

instance (Integral a) => Vectorlike (Vect a) where
    norm (Vect x y) = sqrt . fromIntegral $ x^2 + y^2
-- |
-- >>> norm (Vect 3 4 :: Vect Int)
-- 5.0

instance Vectorlike (Vect Double) where
    norm (Vect x y) = sqrt $ x^2 + y^2
```

but with this, when usnig `norm (Vect 3.0 4.0 :: Vect Double) I get an error

```
Overlapping instances for Vectorlike (Vect Double)
||   print $ norm (Vect 3.0 4.0 :: Vect Double)
foo.hs|40 col 13 error| Overlapping instances for Vectorlike (Vect Double)
||   arising from a use of `norm'
|| Matching instances:
||   instance Integral a => Vectorlike (Vect a)
||     -- Defined at /home/yosh/foo.hs:26:10
||   instance Vectorlike (Vect Double)
||     -- Defined at /home/yosh/foo.hs:32:10
```

My question is how I can define `norm` so that it works for integers and floatings, and the error message is not the main concern (it's puzzling for me, but I think I can work with that afterwards).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use `realToFrac`, which converts any `Real r => r` value to a `Fractional f => f` value:

```
norm :: (Real r, Floating f) => Vect r -> f
norm (Vect x y) = sqrt . realToFrac $ x^2 + y^2
```

Then it will work for even more types than just `Double`, too.

As for the error message, you don't technically have an overlap on those two instances, but you definitely could.  Someone could define an `Integral Double` instance, then import your code.  Suddenly the compiler can't decide which instance to use!

While this precise situation is not likely to happen, the type system does allow someone to instance `Integral` for `Double`, and this certainly can occur with other typeclasses and data types.

Comment: I felt there should be some function, perfect ! And *you definitely could* -- that's the insight I was missing. Both question perfectly solved, thank you!

Comment: @Yosh Sorry, it's better now.  I must have copy/pasted wrong or something.  I read over that line about 3 times and didn't see that I hadn't left the return type polymorphic like I intended.